# Micro data from json

Tags: javascript, json

I was wondering how to get through the testing tool of Google when it comes to rich snippets or micro data and using json data.

The thing is that I don't have the option to use PHP and only javascript. So when I want to grab review data from let's say Trusted Shops for a shop I never get passed the testing tool because the data is always empty when Google crawls the page.

So what I mean is this:

There's a direct link to the json file with the review data

```
http://api.trustedshops.com/rest/public/v2/shops/X17BD396442BCEE0808C79156D0E95F97/quality/reviews.json
```

What I tried is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
      var url = 'http://api.trustedshops.com/rest/public/v2/shops/X17BD396442BCEE0808C79156D0E95F97/quality/reviews.json';

      $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        var stuff = data.response.data;
        var review = stuff.shop.qualityIndicators
         $('#value').html(review.reviewIndicator.overallMark);
         $('#votes').html(review.reviewIndicator.activeReviewCount);
      });
    }
  </script>
```

HTML output

```
<span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" typeof="v:Review-aggregate">
   <span rel="v:rating">
     <span property="v:value" id="value">4.83</span> /
     <span property="v:best" id="best">5.00</span>
   </span> of
     <span property="v:votes" id="votes">58</span> reviews.
   </span>
```

Now with the Testing tool from Google I always get 3 errors saying "can't leave blank...".

Is such thing even possible??

Comment: Your code there seems to work fine, and produces an HTML result. So what _exactly_ are you asking here? Are you asking why your test of that result is failing? Because you haven't at all described what that test is or how it works.

Comment: @AlexWayne: Exactly!! The code works perfectly fine. The only thing is that Google doesn't see the result. Google sees three empty spans instead of the populated spans which we see. Why is that and is there a work around?

Comment: What do you mean by "Google sees"? Through what mechanism is Google "seeing" your page?

Comment: @AlexWayne: Google has a [testing tool for rich snippets]. When using the code above the tool says there are three empty spans. What we see is three spans with data in it. So the question is: Why? and how?(https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

Answer (score 0):

So I have no clue how to use this tool, but none of their examples have javascript in them. I don't think this tool will execute any javascript in the left hand box before it tries to validate the data. There are examples with `<script type="application/ld+json">` tags, but they are just JSON data, and not executable code (note the `type`).

To verify this I simply entered this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('it this on?');
</script>
```

When I click validate, nothing shows up in my browser console.

Whatever you are trying to make this tool do, I think is outside the scope of how it's intended to be used. It appears that this tools can validate the result of your code, but it cannot also run your code.